# Auto VCS tagging on Teamcity build - Limitations?

Tags: continuous-integration, perforce, tagging, limits

There have been concerns that automatically tagging builds with build systems (TeamCity/CruiseControl) will create so many tags that Perforce will be bogged down.

The only references I've managed to find have said "unless you have numbers, don't worry about it."  I'd rather worry now before polluting a 100+G repository.

Does anyone have systems doing 1000+ builds a month that have seen anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using automatic labels, which simply contain a view (the parts of the depot you are identifying) and a revision number (usually a changelist).  Automatic labels put very little metadata in the database.

If you use static labels, you should periodically archive old labels to keep the size of the database under control.

You can find more info on these subjects at the Perforce Knowledge Base.

Comment: Thanks for pointing automatic labels are not something I'd thought of before and something that I'll look in to.  Unfortunately label archiving is the same info I got out of the Perforce Knowledge Base and other sources.  I was actually looking for real world experience with this.  Unfortunately (for me) the repository is shared by many different groups and there's not an easy way for an admin (who is in yet a different group and generally only intervenes when there is a problem) to know what's live/dead/unimportant.

Comment: Perforce tracks the last access time for labels.  A lot of folks have scripts that detect labels that haven't been accessed in some time frame (say 3 months), and mark those for archiving.

Comment: The problem with archiving labels that haven't been accessed in 3 months is that as soon as that archive process occurs someone is going to need it.  We just had an incident today where we referred back to a label two years old.  I did find this link that discussed how to do some of this maintenance: http://blog.perforce.com/blog/?p=187 but we just don't have the perforce admin full time to retrieve archived labels - assuming most of our users knew enough to ask for them.